# Fitnesse: How to stop one test run when executing a suite

Tags: selenium, fitnesse

I am using Fitnesse 20130530 to execute a test suite that contains multiple tests. Most of my tests use script tables with SLIM to drive Selenium. I use a [Stop Test Exception](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.ExceptionHandling) to stop the execution of a test when one of the method calls raises an exception. Unfortunately, this also stops the execution of the whole suite. Is there a way to just stop the current test and then continue execution with the next test in the suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in FitNesse itself, but you can build it into your fixtures.

When I had a similar problem I was able to solve it using what we called "fail fast" mode.  This was a static variable that could be set to true under certain conditions (typically by an element not found exception or similar).

Our main driver was structured such that we could pass through one spot that could check for that value before calling the browserDriver.  This would then skip the broswerDriver calls until the test ended.

The next text would clear the flag and start up again.

You would need to manage the whole process, but it can work.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about the same thing. We already have AspectJ in place and weave our Fixture methods so that would be one way to go. I was hoping that Fitnesse offers a solution for that. I will wait a few more days and then accept your answer if nothing else comes up.